# AMPScript not working with Content Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, content-builder

I have a link in my email.

Link works in Classic Content HTML Paste email whereas same code does not work in Content Builder version.
tried

```
href="%%[RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(123))]%%
href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(123))=%%
```

both render as

`http://cl.***.exct.net/%%[%20CloudPagesURL(123)]%%`

Where as in Classic I am using this

```
href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(123))=%%
```

and it works fine.

Any advise how I can make this to work in Content Builder.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the [**part of the documentation**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/microsite_and_landing_page_ampscript_functions/cloudpagesurl/), I don't think you need the `redirectto()` on the `CloudPagesURL()` function. It should wrap the links properly without it:

`<a href="%%=CloudPagesURL(163)=%%">link</a>`

Comment: I think you're correct. Surplus to requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You may have clipped something when pasting your examples into StackExchange as there doesn't look like too much wrong with your examples. Here's an example tracked URL to a Cloud Page working in Content Builder...

```
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(163))=%%" alias="Update Preferences">Update Preferences</a>
```